# Como retirar os campos de coluna de um select com expressão regular?

Tags: javascript, sql, regex

Estou precisando utilizar uma expressão regular em JavaScript para saber quais as colunas passadas em uma consulta `select`.

Por exemplo: passando `"SELECT nome, sobrenome FROM table"` a expressão me retornaria `"nome,sobrenome"`. Há alguma forma de conseguir isso?

Comment: Precisa ser com expressão regular? Da para fazer de forma normal, já que sempre será um SELECT e um FROM no meio das colunas

Comment: No caso, utilizando substr?

Comment: Isso, mas estou montando uma regex aqui

Comment: Matheus, vi que vc removeu a aceitação da resposta. Ficou faltando alguma coisa?

Comment: No caso, a explicação foi bem completa mas nenhuma das alternativas funcionou pra mim.

Comment: Bom, a alternativa com `map` e `trim` dá exatamente o mesmo resultado da outra resposta. Mas tudo bem, que bom que encontrou a solução :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia fazer utilizando substring mas já que quer com regex eu montei uma aqui, para pegar os valores entre SELECT e FROM.

```js
const texto = "SELECT nome, sobrenome FROM table";

const colunas = texto.match(/(?<=SELECT)(.*)(?=FROM)/i)[0].replace(/\s/g, "").split(",").join();

console.log(colunas);
```

**Explicando a Regex**

`?<=` - **Positive Lookbehind** = Básicamente coloca como ponto inicial da regex algo que esteja depois dele, no caso `?<=SELECT` coloca como ponto inicial
`nome, sobrenome...`, pegando tudo que está depois do SELECT.

`(.*)` - Pega qualquer caracter

`?=` - **Positive Lookahead**  = Básicamente faz o mesmo que a lookbehind porém ao inverso, pega tudo o que está antes.

`/i` - Quer dizer que não vai ser case sensitive, ou seja, tanto faz maiuscula ou minuscula

Comment: Refatoração: Como você já está utilizando a *flag* `/i`, torna-se desnecessário usar *SELECT|select*.

Comment: Boa @ValdeirPsr, estou montando a explicação da regex, ai já conserto

Answer (score 2):

Depende. Se você garante que as queries sempre são válidas, e que vai estar tudo na mesma linha, o mais simples é:

```js
let query = "SELECT nome, sobrenome FROM table";
let m = query.match(/select(.+)from/i);
console.log(m[1]); // nome, sobrenome
```

Basicamente, o [ponto](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) corresponde a "qualquer coisa", e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` quer dizer "uma ou mais ocorrências". Isso quer dizer que entre o "select" e o "from" pode ter um ou mais caracteres.

O `.+` está entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), assim eu consigo pegá-lo com `m[1]` (eu uso `1` porque é o primeiro grupo de captura, já que é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex).

A [flag `i`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) torna a regex *case insensitive* (não diferencia letras maiúsculas e minúsculas), assim tanto faz se a query tiver `"select"`, `"SELECT"`, `"Select"`, etc. O mesmo vale para o `"from"`.

O código acima retorna os nomes das colunas do jeito que estiverem na query, então se tiver vários espaços entre elas, estes serão retornados também. Mas se quiser que a saída seja com apenas vírgulas, sem espaços, basta separar tudo com [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) e depois juntar de novo com [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) (ou usar [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) junto com [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim), que elimina os espaços):

```js
let query = "SELECT nome,     sobrenome   ,    outrocampo FROM table";
let m = query.match(/select(.+)from/i);
console.log(m[1]); // nome,     sobrenome   ,    outrocampo 

console.log(m[1].split(/\s*,\s*/).join(',')); // nome,sobrenome,outrocampo 
console.log(m[1].split(/,/).map(s => s.trim()).join(',')); // nome,sobrenome,outrocampo
```

Eu uso o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s` (que pega espaços, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, quebras de linha, etc - veja a lista completa na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#Types)) com o quantificador `*` (zero ou mais ocorrências), assim eu elimino as vírgulas e os espaços que possam ter antes ou depois. Por fim, no `join`, eu uso apenas a vírgula para juntar os nomes das colunas.

Repare que a segunda opção com `map` e `trim` elimina também os espaços no início e fim da string. Também daria para eliminar esses espaços usando a regex `/select\s+(.+)\s+from/i`.

---

Essa regex é **bem** ingênua. Ela não valida nada, então a query pode ser `"SELECT FROM"` ou `"abcSELECT *** FROMxyz"`, que mesmo assim ela pega o que tiver entre o "select" e o "from":

```js
let r = /select(.+)from/i;
console.log("select from".match(r)[1]); // imprime um espaço em branco
console.log("abcselect *** fromxyz".match(r)[1]); // ***
```

---

Se quer validar que tenha pelo menos alguma coisa entre o "select" e o "from", pode incrementar a regex. Por exemplo, para o caso mais simples, com um ou mais nomes de colunas:

```js
function extraiColunas(s) {
    let r = /\bselect\s+([a-z]+(\s*,\s*[a-z]+)*)\s+from\b/i;
    let m = s.match(r);
    if (m) {
        console.log(m[1]);
    } else {
        console.log('query inválida');
    }
}

extraiColunas("select nome, sobrenome from tabela"); // nome, sobrenome
extraiColunas("abcselect nome, sobrenome fromxyz"); // query inválida
extraiColunas("select **** from table"); // query inválida
```

Agora eu uso o [*word boundary*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` para garantir que antes do "select" e depois do "from" não há outras letras. Também uso o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s`, ora com `+` (para um ou mais), ora com `*` (para zero ou mais).

Para os nomes das colunas, usei a abordagem mais ingênua: a [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[a-z]+` (uma ou mais letras de `a` a `z`). E como eu usei a *flag* `i`, a regex já considera também as letras maiúsculas de `A` a `Z`.

A parte `(\s*,\s*[a-z]+)*` diz que todo o trecho "espaços, vírgula, espaços, uma ou mais letras" pode se repetir zero ou mais vezes (indicado pelo `*` depois dos parênteses). Ou seja, eu posso ter apenas um nome (indicado pelo primeiro `[a-z]+`, antes desses parênteses), ou vários nomes separados por vírgula.

---

Mas claro que ainda não acabou. E se a query tiver algo como `"select count(*)"` ou `"select nome as primeiro_nome"`, a regex teria que ser adaptada para contemplar estes casos. Ou ainda `"select total1 + total2"` e outras expressões válidas (repare que também não incluí `"select * from"` nos exemplos acima, e a regex nem valida se tem algo depois do "from").

Aí você tem que decidir se vai complicar ainda mais a regex para considerar todos os casos, ou se vai usar a expressão mais simples (`.+`) sob o risco de aceitar queries inválidas.

---

Outro problema do ponto é que ele pode pegar coisas a mais, por exemplo:

```js
let query = "SELECT nome, sobrenome FROM table_from where x > 1";
let m = query.match(/select(.+)from/i);
console.log(m[1]); // nome, sobrenome FROM table_
```

Repare que ele pegou `"nome, sobrenome FROM table_"`. Isso acontece porque os quantificadores `+` e `*` são [gananciosos](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) por padrão, e tentam pegar o maior número possível de caracteres. No caso, o ponto vai até a última ocorrência de "from" que encontrar. Se tivesse uma subquery depois, por exemplo, a regex iria até o "from" desta.

No caso de queries mais simples como essa, daria para resolver com `\s`, já que depois do "select" e antes do "from" deve ter pelo menos um espaço:

```js
let query = "SELECT nome, sobrenome FROM table_from where x > 1";
let m = query.match(/select\s+(.+)\s+from/i);
console.log(m[1]); // nome, sobrenome
```

Mas ainda sim, dependendo das queries que você vai avaliar, pode ser que surjam outros problemas. Não tem jeito, se quer deixar a regex mais simples, a chance de falsos positivos aumenta, e se quiser tratar mais casos e diminuir a chance de pegar queries inválidas, a complexidade da regex aumenta. Cabe a você avaliar até onde vale a pena complicar a regex.

---

Ou simplesmente use um [*parser* de SQL](https://www.google.com/search?q=js%20parse%20sql). [Regex nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

---

**PS:** a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405010/112052) usa [*lookbehind* e *lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), que também funciona, mas é um pouco mais custoso. Compare [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/67CEyr/1/) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/KQz585/2/) a quantidade de passos executados (isso para uma query pequena, a diferença já é quase o dobro de passos). Claro que para poucas strings pequenas a diferença será de milissegundos ou até menos, mas é importante saber as implicações de usar uma coisa ou outra.

Na outra resposta também é usado `.*`, mas como o `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências", ela vai aceitar inclusive a string `"selectfrom"`. É o que eu já disse, quanto mais simples a regex, maior a chance de falsos positivos (e não que usar `.+` seja **tão** melhor assim que `.*`, conforme já explicado acima).